# Spliting json data

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following example to split the json data

```
var data = [ 
  { BankName: 'SBI', IFSC: 'SBIN0002688' },
  { BankName: 'ICICI', IFSC: 'ICIC0003931', MICR: '500229094'},
  { BankName: 'RBI', IFSC: 'RBIS0GOTGEP' },
  { BankName: 'CITI', IFSC: 'CITI0000047', MICR: '500229034'} 
]
```

I need the results here:

```
let result = [
  {BankName: 'SBI', 'Codes': ['SBIN0002688']},
  {BankName: 'ICICI', 'Codes': ['ICIC0003931','500229094']},
  {BankName: 'RBI', 'Codes': ['RBIS0GOTGEP']},
  {BankName: 'CITI', 'Codes': ['CITI0000047','500229034']}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the data and then for each item, isolate the `BankName` from the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) of the properties (assuming that the rest of the properties are "Codes").

```js
var data = [ { BankName: 'SBI', IFSC: 'SBIN0002688' }, 
  { BankName: 'ICICI', IFSC: 'ICIC0003931',MICR : '500229094'},
  { BankName: 'RBI', IFSC: 'RBIS0GOTGEP' }, 
  { BankName: 'CITI', IFSC: 'CITI0000047',MICR : '500229034'} ]

const result = data.map(({ BankName, ...codes }) => ({
  BankName,
  Codes: Object.values(codes),
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [
  { BankName: 'SBI', IFSC: 'SBIN0002688' },
  { BankName: 'ICICI', IFSC: 'ICIC0003931', MICR: '500229094' },
  { BankName: 'RBI', IFSC: 'RBIS0GOTGEP' },
  { BankName: 'CITI', IFSC: 'CITI0000047', MICR: '500229034' },
];

const result = data.map((val) => {
  return {
    BankName: val.BankName,
    Codes: val.MICR ? [val.IFSC, val.MICR] : [val.IFSC],
  };
});
```

The above snippet should work